# Can I merge these two URL patterns?

Tags: python, django

I am wondering if it's necessary to have these two patterns in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^books/author/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'books.views.author'),
url(r'^books/author/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'books.views.author'),
```

Basically, slug is optional. And view function definition is like this:

```
def author(request, id, slug=None):
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the second group and the slash in a non-capturing group and make that whole group optional:

```
r'^books/author/(?P<id>\d+)/(?:(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/)?$'
```